# Find what generic type parameters are specified or inferred at each call site in a source generator?

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

In a C# source generator, how can I find what types are being used at each call site for a given generic method?

Say I have a class `App` and a member method `RunSystem<T>(Action<T> action)`. It could be called like this (without type inference):

```csharp
App app = new();
app.RunSystem<SomeType>(SomeOtherMethod);
```

Or like this (with type inference):

```csharp
App app = new();
app.RunSystem((SomeType someType) => { });
```

Depending on how it's called, the syntax tree changes. In the first example, I need to find the types from the generic parameters. In the second example, I need to find the types of the lambda parameters. This appears to be quite difficult and I'm not sure how to be certain I've covered every case.

This is what I have so far:

```csharp
[Generator]
public class Generator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context) { }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        foreach(var syntaxTree in context.Compilation.SyntaxTrees)
        {
            var semanticModel = context.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);

            var invExpSyntaxes = syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();

            foreach(var invExpSyntax in invExpSyntaxes)
            {
                var invExpSymbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invExpSyntax).Symbol;
                if(invExpSymbol.ContainingType.Name == "App" && invExpSymbol.ContainingNamespace.Name == "SomeNamespace")
                {
                    var methodSymbol = (IMethodSymbol)invExpSymbol;
                    // Now what?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't yet narrow down the method to be the one I'm looking for, but otherwise it seems to work to find methods in the right class and namespace.

From here, how can I find what generic type parameters are passed in or inferred at each call site?

Alternate (better, less janky) methods of finding all call sites of a method are welcome.

---

### More Information...

**...for the purpose of not getting stuck with an X/Y question**

I'm experimenting with creating a [Bevy](https://bevyengine.org)-style ECS in C#. I'm aware it may not be feasible, but I'm attempting to explore all avenues before deciding.

What I want to be able to do is this:

```csharp
public void Main()
{
    App app = new();
    app
      .AddSystem(SomeSystem)
      .AddSystem(SomeOtherSystem);
}

public struct Health : IComponent { /* some data */ }
public struct Transform : IComponent { /* some data */ }
public struct Velocity : IComponent { /* some data */ }

public void SomeSystem(Query<(Health, Transform)> query)
{
    foreach((Health, Velocity) componentGroup in query)
    {
        // do stuff on the entities
    }
}

public void SomeOtherSystem(Query<(Transform, Velocity), Without<Health>> query)
{
    foreach((Transform, Velocity) componentGroup in query)
    {
        // do stuff on the entities
    }
}

public void SomeThirdSystem(Commands commands, Query<Health> query)
{
    foreach(Health healthComponent in query)
    {
        // do stuff on the entities
        // also use commands to queue up spawning/despawning of entities etc.
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fill in the `AddSystem` and `Query` parts, for which I believe I need to use source generators (someone actually came up with a [fantastic solution](https://discord.com/channels/691052431525675048/1085900864247562250/1085920578684334191) using `Expression`s, but I'm avoiding that for now because it won't work on AOT platforms).

Through some Rust magic I haven't fully understood yet, Bevy allows [system functions](https://bevy-cheatbook.github.io/programming/systems.html) to use any combination of [System Parameters](https://bevy-cheatbook.github.io/builtins.html#systemparams). For instance, in my "ultimate goal" code above, `Query<Q>`, `Query<Q, F>` and `Commands` would all be considered System Parameters.

I'm aware this is a very unusual usage of C# (or any language really) but I'm finding that doing it the more "usual" C# way (which I assume would involve an abstract `System` base class from which each concrete system class would derive - I haven't actually tried implementing that yet) creates a vastly more verbose and tedious syntax.

It's almost trivial in comparison to implement this using only reflection and DynamicInvoke, but given I'm creating an ECS game engine, performance is a pretty strong focus.

Comment: Yeah, you basically have to reimplement the same logic that C# compiler has. You need to analyze parameters, their types and find appropriate method match. Not trivial, for sure. And time consuming. And error prone.

Comment: @freakish That sounds... not very useful. Am I doing things wrong? Is this not how people usually use source generators? I can't imagine ever being able to achieve anything useful with sourcegen if it relies on such a fragile and fiddly system. I always just assumed there would be helper methods to make this stuff easy, and the lack of such is very out-of-character for C# and .NET.

Comment: I think it is rather rare to use source generators the way you do it here. Typically we would have some custom attribute, some class marked with this attribute and we would generate a code based on fields/properties. For example json serialization. Analyzing method calls is a lot harder, and it requires deeper knowledge of C# standard. So maybe we should start with the most important question: what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @freakish Certainly it's possible this is an X/Y question. I've updated the question with detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at a similar problem while converting a `System.Reflection.Emit` based project to an incremental generator. It is somewhat disappointing that the Roslyn APIs don't expose this information (I don't know the specific details behind the .NET source code, but surely the compiler must know the type argument substitutions!).

I resorted to capturing **every** `GenericNameSyntax` and `InvocationExpressionSyntax` in the compilation, and using the `SemanticModel` to get the relevant `INamedTypeSymbol` or `IMethodSymbol`. This seems to be the only reliable way (AFAICT) to make sure that you can capture instances where *nested* type parameters are discovered (e.g., if you have a generic method inside of a generic class, where some or all of the method's type parameters are provided by the class' type parameters).

From there, I produced the [GenericSymbolTree](https://gist.github.com/monkey0506/63ac2f765413285f21fac88101aa2c5a). The `AddOrUpdateBranch` method will ensure that the `ISymbol` does indeed have `TypeArguments`, and if any of those type arguments are unsubstituted type *parameters*, then further inspection is done when calling `GetCompletedSymbolsForBranch`.

I am posting shortly after completing this code, and while I have tested it in limited scenarios, there may be errors or unseen consequences behind the methodology of capturing every generic class and **every method call** in the compilation. Any feedback is welcomed. Hopefully this can push you in the right direction to discover the symbols you need.

I'll also note that many of the source generator examples I've seen online have echoed the comments above that it is "rather rare to use source generators" in this manner. I don't fully understand the context of your application, but in my case, I am attempting to provide an API of generic `interface`s that are backed by generated code which **requires** knowledge of the actual type arguments. This isn't a case of merely discovering the `interface` declarations with an applied attribute, I need to discover the actual *call sites*. In that way, your application sounds similar to what I am working on. Rarity of the application doesn't inherently imply that it is invalid, and from what I do understand, your use case seems to be valid albeit unusual.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up shelving that experiment, however I've been wanting to come back to it; maybe now is the time. I don't quite recall exactly what I was trying to do, but I think I was trying to sourcegen some code to call each added "system" function in a non-dynamic way with the appropriate arguments. The tricky part is that the arguments to the systems are specified by the user and my code can't know them ahead of time, and also the type arguments are used to determine which data types to pass, which I know is quite a strange use of the language. Something like that, anyway.